# How to Re-arrange items in a Python Dictionary during For Loop?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am building a Python dictionary from a table in Excel. It's a `Category:Name` relationship. So, the first column in the spreadsheet is a category and the second column is the name of a file:

- Forests - Tree Type
- Forests - Soil Type
- Administrative - Cities
- Administrative - Buildings
- Mineral - Gold
- Mineral - Platinum
- Water - Watershed
- Water - Rivers
- Water - Lakes
- Water - Streams

and so on...

I use this code to build the dictionary:

```
layerListDict = dict()
for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(xls):  

    # Set condition to pull out the Name field in the xls file. 
    # LayerList being the list of all the 'Name' from the 'Name' column built earlier in the script

    if str(row.getValue("Name")).rstrip() in layerList:

        # Determine if the category item is in the dictionary as a key already. If so, then append the Name to the list of values associated with the category 
        if row.getValue("Category") in layerListDict:
            layerListDict[row.getValue("Category")].append(str(row.getValue("Name")))
        # if not, create a new category key and add the associated Name value to it
        else:
            layerListDict[row.getValue("Category")] = [str(row.getValue("Name"))]
```

So, now I have a dictionary with Category as the key and a list of Names as the values:

> {u'Forests': ['Tree Type', 'Soil Type'], u'Administrative': ['Cities', 'Buildings'], u'Mineral': ['Gold', 'Platinum'], u'Water': ['Watershed', 'Rivers', 'Lakes', 'Streams']}

I can now iterate over the sorted dictionary by key:

```
for k,v in sorted(layerListDict.iteritems()):
      print k, v
```

**PROBLEM:** What I would like to do is to iterate over the sorted dictionary with one caveat...I wanted to have the 'Mineral' key to be the very first key and then have the rest of the keys print out in alphabetical order like this:

- Mineral ['Gold', 'Platinum']
- Administrative ['Cities', 'Buildings']
- Forests ['Tree Type', 'Soil Type']
- Water ['Watershed', 'Rivers', 'Lakes', 'Streams']

Can anyone suggest how I can accomplish this?

I tried to set a variable to a sorted list, but it returns as a python list and I cannot iterate over the Python list by a key value pair anymore.

```
List2 = sorted(layerListDict.iteritems())
```

> [u'Forests':['Tree Type', 'Soil Type'], u'Administrative': ['Cities', 'Buildings'], u'Mineral': ['Gold', 'Platinum'], u'Water': ['Watershed', 'Rivers', 'Lakes', 'Streams']]

Comment: See univerio's answer, in addition you should look into using a defaultdict: `layerListDict = collections.defaultdict(list)`. It will get rid of your inner `if` (and all the duplicated code in it).

Comment: Also, do you know all of the possible categories ahead of time (or have a way to determine them)? Thought of a way better answer than the one I gave if you do.

Comment: The categories are pulled from a column in spreadsheet. I'm doing this so that anyone can go into the spreadsheet and add/remove items as they wish, so the list of categories will be dynamic in the sense that whatever is in the category column, needs to be in the key value of the dictionary when the script is run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An overly general solution:

```
import itertools
first = 'Mineral'
for k, v in itertools.chain([(first, layersListDict[first])], 
                            ((k,v) for (k,v) in layerListDict.iteritems() if k != first)):
    print k, v
```

or closer to my original incorrect solution:

```
for k, layersListDict[k] in itertools.chain((first,),
                                             (k for k in layerListDict
                                               if k != first)):
    print k, v
```

Comment: This returns "too many values to unpack" because I believe you are building a list in your for loop, so now there is no key, value pairs?

Comment: Like I said, overly general :) Fixed (or will be, in a moment).

Comment: Ha! thanks chepner. I was thinking an iteritems needed to be in there somewhere. Clever fix.

Comment: @Mike: Clever is not always better. In the comments for another answer, you mention that you are "not great with functions". I think you're better served becoming more comfortable with functions before delving into `itertools`, especially since this problem really doesn't need it. (Don't get me wrong, `itertools` is an excellent module; but pulling it out to rearrange one element in a collection is a bit overkill.) Until you're more advanced, I recommend sticking to what's simple. (And when you *are* more advanced, you should *still* stick to what's simple when you can!)

Answer (score 4):

```
print "Mineral", layerListDict.pop("Mineral")
for k, v in sorted(layerListDict.iteritems()):
    print k, v
```

If you don't want to modify `layerListDict`:

```
print "Mineral", layerListDict["Mineral"]
for k, v in sorted(layerListDict.iteritems()):
    if k != "Mineral":
        print k, v
```

Comment: How does this print the 'Minerals' inside the loop first and the the remaining keys in alphabectical order?

Comment: In the first example, it prints "Minerals" outside of the loop and then removes it from the `dict`.

Comment: Thanks. Good ideas, but unfortauntely neither one of these solutions will work for what i need to do. I need to print  everything inside the loop (my print lines are actually write lines in my code), starting with 'Mineral' and the rest in alphabectical order....

Comment: Why does it matter where you print/write these values?

Comment: The amount of code that comes afterwards. I'd have to do a lot of duplication and modification if I did 'Mineral' outside of the for loop.

Comment: So put the loop contents in a function.

Comment: You're absolutely right univero. I should use the rest of my code in a function. Sorry, I'm not great with functions (I know...lame). I just wanted something easy to fit in with all the code I wrote from before. I need to start learning to use functions properly!

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to print the key-value pairs, then the other solutions get the job done quite well. If you're looking for the resulting dictionary to have a certain order so that you can perform other operations on it, you should look into the OrderedDict class:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Objects are stored in the order that they are inserted. In your case, you would do something similar to the other answers first to define the order:

```
dict_tuples = sorted(layerListDict.items())
ordered_tuples = [("Mineral", layerListDict["Mineral"],)]
ordered_tuples += [(k, v,) for k, v in dict_tuples if k != "Mineral"]
ordered_dict = collections.OrderedDict(ordered_tuples) #assumes import happened above
```

Now you can do whatever you want with ordered_dict (careful with deleting then reinserting, see the link above). Don't know if that helps you more than some of the other answers (which are all pretty great!).

EDIT: Whoops, my recollection of the update behavior of OrderedDicts was a bit faulty. Fixed above. Also streamlined the code a little. You could potentially generate the tuples in your first for loop and then put them in the OrderedDict, too.

EDIT 2: Forgot that tuples are naturally sorted by the first element (thanks John Y), removed the unnecessary key param in the sorted() call.

Comment: Err, I edited it to try to make it simpler. Let me know if I broke it or you don't like it anymore, and I can try to fix it up some.

Comment: I did break it! Fixed now.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that your "streamlined" version is actually more streamlined. You reduced the number of lines by one, but now each line is harder to read and the whole scheme is less clear (not horrible, but not as dead-simple as before). Also, why do you need the `key` parameter for `sorted` when you're just going to use natural sort order anyway?

Comment: Ah, fair point on the sorting, forgot that tuples are naturally sorted by the first element. As for the overall streamlined...ness, I was trying to reduce the number of ancillary/intermediate structures. In this case, I didn't want to have the list of keys then ALSO the original dict. But yeah, might be harder to read. Think I should change it back?

Comment: Hmm... up to you. I think I am realizing one more factor that makes your newer version feel less clean to me (my personal taste only!) and that is the trailing commas in the tuples. I suppose you got into that habit so that ALL parenthesized tuples have trailing commas, not just one-element tuples, but I find it adds clutter. (And then your unparenthesized tuple *doesn't* have the extra comma.) Ultimately, it's your answer; as long as it works, you should make it best fit your own sensibilities.

Comment: Ah, on my team we're super into the trailing comma for parenthesized tuples, so I'm used to using it (though I actually don't like it either). I added a second answer below though that I'm hoping is both more visually appealing and performant, so I'll leave this one as is as long as it isn't doing any damage to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a list of keys in the order you want to iterate over the map.  Then iterate through the list, using the values as keys into the map.

Actually, after seeing the other solutions, I like chepner's answer with itertools.chain() better, especially if the list of keys is large, because mine will move things around in the list too much.

```
# sort the keys
keyList = sorted(keys(layerListDict))
# remove 'Mineral' from it's place
del keyList[keyList.index('Mineral')]
# Put it in the beginning
keyList = ['Mineral'] + keyList

# Iterate
for k in keyList:
    for v in layerListDict[k]:
        print k, v
```

Comment: I don't think performance should be a consideration unless OP specifically brings it up. It's usually best to just try something simple and understandable (which your stated approach is), and then only if that is too slow, try more advanced techniques. That said, your code has some issues. First, if you're trying to get the keys of `layerListDict`, it's `layerListDict.keys()`. Less critical, but affecting readability: To remove a value from a list, just use the `remove` method (so `keyList.remove('Mineral')`).

Answer (score 0):

Second shot at an answer. This is pretty different from my original, and makes some possibly wrong assertions, but I like the feel of it a lot better. Since you're able to determine all of the values in the "name" column (layerList), I'm going to assume you can do the same for the "categories" column. This code assumes you've placed your categories (including "Mineral") into an unsorted list called `categories`, and replaces the original code:

```
categories.sort()
categories = ["Mineral"] + [cat for cat in categories if cat != "Mineral"]

# Insert the categories into our dict with placeholder lists that we can append to
layerListDict = collections.OrderedDict([(cat, [],) for cat in categories])

for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(xls):
    if str(row.getValue("Name")).rstrip() in layerList:
        layerListDict[row.getValue("Category")].append(str(row.getValue("Name")))
```

Now you can just iterate over layerListDict.items().